# Removing a null post

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers

I've come across answers like:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13206332/249341

Which (saved for posterity) look like:

> Please delete this answer. See my comment. Sorry for editing this way.

and the comment:

> Unable to delete this, or flag. Can someone please flag for deletion? I don't want to register.

Where it is unequivocally clear that the answer should be removed. How can I as a mid-rep user (4K) deal with this? Should I post to the meta for a cleanup request? I don't like the idea of leaving it up because it **adds no value**(tm) to the site.

Comment: _You_ could flag it.

Comment: @Ben Is that the proper way to remove it then (for my level of rep)? If so, I'll take that as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flag it as not an answer. If you see a delete link, click it.

if a glance at the edit history makes you think this is vandalism or rage-quitting (confirm by opening the user's profile in a new tab and checking a few answers) then flag as Other and say the user is wiping out a whole pile of answers at once. Consider rolling back to a previous version if that version looks useful.

Comment: *Always* rollback.  It is *never* appropriate for users to vandalize their own content.

Comment: If they completely got the wrong idea and answered something totally unrelated then it could be ok to delete it. Eg someone wants to read and parse a file and the answer is how to write text to a file.

Comment: Yeah, but *answers* can always be deleted by the user, can't they?

Comment: I think if they have an upvote they can't.